# Is there a way of updating blender with all of my files contained?

Tags: blend-files

I want to update blender to the latest version, 2.77, I'm currently using 2.75, and I know you can update blender by reinstalling the program, but my only concern is that would my files be imported into the next version.

And if not, how would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Your .blend files will still be accessible. Blender is backwards compatible way past 2.75.

Answer (score 0):

There's no risk of losing any of your files when you update or uninstall Blender. Blender is very nicely backwards and forwards compatible, lately I've used nearly all 2.7 releases to work on my files on many systems.

If you manually delete some directories for the old install location, make sure they don't contain some of your .blend files since for some setups Blender install directory is the default file saving location.